# Is it possible to change a BigQuery table encryption from default to CMEK encryption via the API/Client Library

Tags: google-bigquery

Given an existing BigQuery table using default google managed encryption, is it possible via the API (patch) or Python Client Library (client.update_table) to change the encryption to use a Customer Managed Encryption Key (CMEK)? Using the API browser and python client no errors are thrown however the table remains using the default encryption. All the examples in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/customer-managed-encryption) reference copying the table. I'm trying to understand if it is possible to change the encryption_configuration in place. Sample python code below:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

PROJECT = 'x'
DATASET = 'x'
TABLE = 'x'
KMSKEY = 'x'


client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT)
dataset_ref = client.dataset(DATASET)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(TABLE)
bq_table = client.get_table(table_ref)

bq_table.encryption_configuration = bigquery.EncryptionConfiguration(kms_key_name=KMSKEY)

bq_table = client.update_table(bq_table, ['encryption_configuration'])  

assert bq_table.encryption_configuration.kms_key_name == KMSKEY
```

Output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_cmek_update.py", line 20, in <module>
    assert bq_table.encryption_configuration.kms_key_name == KMSKEY
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kms_key_name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can essentially change to KMS protection in place by copying a table on to itself. In the relevant python [example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/customer-managed-encryption#change_to_kms), you should set the `dest_dataset_ref` and `dest_table_ref` to be the same as the `source` ones and then configure the copy job to have 
 `WRITE_TRUNCATE` write disposition, adding the following line:
`job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'`

To do the same via REST API, run:

```
alias gcurl='curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" '

gcurl -X POST -T "kms_request.json" https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$PROJECT/jobs
```

where `kms_request.json` would be:

```
{
"configuration": {
  "jobType": "COPY",
  "copy": {
   "sourceTable": {
    "projectId": "[PROJECT]",
    "datasetId": "[DATASET]",
    "tableId": "[TABLE]"
   },
   "destinationTable": {
    "projectId": "[PROJECT]",
    "datasetId": "[DATASET]",
    "tableId": "[TABLE]"
   },
   "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
   "destinationEncryptionConfiguration": {
   "kmsKeyName": "projects/[PROJECT]/locations/[KMS_KEY_LOCATION]/keyRings/[KMS_KEY_RING]/cryptoKeys/[KMS_KEY]"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm assuming this means all the data will be copied and thus on large tables would be relatively time consuming. Will users still be able to access the "source" table whilst the copy is in progress - I would presume it's copying to a new table and then doing a metadata operation at the end

Comment: Accessing the source table while running the above "self-copy" might not be possible - I've been trying to do it and I've been getting consistently a RejectedExecutionException from a concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask. How big are these tables? For example, copying tables of 2.5TB takes me 5 to 8 seconds under normal circumstances.